# How do I check an input against prohibited words in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

Hypothetically, if I didn't want to allow the word "douche" anywhere in a username and I have a table in my database with all of the prohibited words...

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM restrictions WHERE prohibited LIKE '%username%'";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) !== 0)
{
//username is prohibited
echo "invalid";
}
else
{
...etc
```

The problem is that I don't know how to execute a query that would pick up partial matches (ie. Jdoucher, or douchebag4).  The %username% part is obviously wrong, I know.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Is it even possible?  Thanks.

Comment: You could probably have written this question without that particular, well, colloquialism.

Comment: LOL @ whoever flagged this question as "offensive"

Comment: My list will be very minimal, so some stuff will definitely get through.  Also, I'm not auto-replacing any text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
    from restrictions 
    where locate(prohibited, @username) <> 0
```

Comment: +1. I was trying to find the proper function for doing this in a pure SQL way.  Now I know. :)

Comment: @David: Can you post some sample data and results?

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM restrictions
    WHERE locate( prohibited, douche )  
  
#1054 - Unknown column 'douche' in 'where clause'

Comment: @David: duoche needs to be quoted as a literal string: `'douche'` or passed in as a variable as in my sample code.

Comment: select * from restrictions where locate (prohibited, @douche)  returns an empty result.

Comment: Are you setting the value of @douche before referencing it in the query in this case? `set @douche = 'douche'`

Comment: Thank you.  I always miss small technical things.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: With this you need to handle cases where the prohibeted word forms part of another word: "douchebag" would (presumably) also be banned, but "Scunthorpe" should be allowed despite letters 2-5.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do the opposite of the example you gave.  Get all of the prohibited keywords first then look for each word in the username:

```
if (stripos($username, $word) !== FALSE) {
   // uhoh
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex match based on simshaun's answer would probably be the faster answer.

Of course if your database of words is too long you're looking at time to process and large memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [regex](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Regular_Expression_Searches).